# How to display Android Settings with only one Group?

Tags: android, android-settings

My app contains only one Settings group called "About".

I generate the SettingsActivity using android studios (New> Activity> Settings Activity) and modified the files in res/xml to reduce the 3 default groups into 1.

the issue I face is that I need to click on Settings  **twice** to access my settings.

- Click Settings > Shows Settings page containing About Group
- Click About group> Shows "my settings in About Group"

How can I make it such that the "About" group is shown when I click "Settings"?
Ideally, the solution should not use deprecated method calls.

- Click Settings > Shows "my settings in About Group"

The following is the ActivitySettings.java codes that I adapted from the autogenerated file.

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatPreferenceActivity {


    private static final List<String> fragments = new ArrayList<>();

    /**
     * Helper method to determine if the device has an extra-large screen. For
     * example, 10" tablets are extra-large.
     */
    private static boolean isXLargeTablet(Context context) {
        return (context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout
                & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE;
    }



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setupActionBar();
    }

    /**
     * Set up the {@link android.app.ActionBar}, if the API is available.
     */
    private void setupActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            // Show the Up button in the action bar.
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == android.R.id.home) {
            if (!super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item)) {
                NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            }
            return true;
        }
        return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onIsMultiPane() {
        return isXLargeTablet(this);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> target) {
        loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.pref_headers, target);

        fragments.clear();
        Queryable.from(target).forEachR(header ->
                fragments.add(header.fragment));
    }


    /**
     * This method stops fragment injection in malicious applications.
     * Make sure to deny any unknown fragments here.
     */
    protected boolean isValidFragment(String fragmentName) {
        return PreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName)
                || fragments.contains(fragmentName); 
    } 

    /**
     * This fragment shows data and sync preferences only. It is used when the
     * activity is showing a two-pane settings UI.
     */
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public static class AboutPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_about);

            findPreference("pref_about_version").setSummary(BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME);
            setGameRules((RulesDialogPreference) findPreference("pref_game_rules"));

        }
    }

    private static void setGameRules(RulesDialogPreference gameRules) {

        gameRules.setList( );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have read the comment provided in the starting lines,

> - A {@link PreferenceActivity} that presents a set of application settings. On
> - handset devices, settings are presented as a single list. On tablets,
> - settings are split by category, with category headers shown to the left of
> - the list of settings.

```
public void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> target) {
    loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.pref_headers, target);
}
```

Above method is adding those header which is shown as left side list items in tablets.

To show directly the preference screen you may use below code, its modified from the generated sample code in android studio, it will solve your purpose.

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Display the fragment as the main content.
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(android.R.id.content, new GeneralPreferenceFragment())
                .commit();
    }


    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public static class GeneralPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_general);
        }
    }
}
```

For more reference go through [Preference Activity and Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#Fragment)